# Как удалить связанные строки в нескольких таблицах.

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с записями о некоторых сущностях (далее главная таблица).
И есть около 10-и таблиц с записями, связанными с каждой сущностью из главной таблицы.
Есть условие, по которому нужно удалить записи из главной таблицы.
Какой должен быть формат SQL оператора, чтобы удалить также все связанные записи из всех таблиц?

Comment: [Вот тоже самое](http://sqlinfo.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4140) обсуждалось. Если не поможет - пишите. :)

Comment: а что не поможет-то? так и есть. :)

Answer (score 1):

Внешние ключи с каскадным удалением решают проблему.

Comment: А если MyISAM? Или это сейчас без разницы?

Comment: Я ориентируюсь на метки. :-)
Стоит только SQL, потому я предлагаю стандартное решение.

Comment: он же "формат SQL оператора" попросил :))

Comment: Формат известный :-)
DELETE FROM <таблица> WHERE <условие>

Comment: DELETE `user`, `usergroup` FROM `user` LEFT JOIN `usergroup` ON `usergroup_user_id`=`user_id` WHERE `user_id`='1' - я вот совсем недавно узнал об этом :)) что можно джойнить и в DELETE :)   хотя это же логично, раз Джойн - это часть Фром

Comment: 1. Вещь нестандартная.
2. Приходится перечислять таблицы. А раз так, то с таким же успехом можно было выполнить отдельные delete для каждой из них. А если вы что-то забудете, то данные станут несогласованными. 
Смысл каскадного удаления в том, что мы используем только одну главную таблицу. Из всех подчиненных соответствующие строки удаляются автоматически, обеспечивая согласованность данных.

Comment: не, ну это все понятно - понятно что каскадное удаление ЛУЧШЕ, но ведь его надо задавать а) при создании/изменении структуры таблицы и б) только для InnoDB.
А насчет нестандартности - это не АНСИ такая конструкция?

Comment: : но ведь его надо задавать

Если в перспективе вы можете получить несогласованные данные, я не будут сильно переживать по этому поводу - не мои это проблемы. :-)

: А насчет нестандартности - это не АНСИ такая конструкция?

Точно. Удалить данные можно только из одной таблицы.